# SQL column name same as PL/SQL variable name - How can this be done in a select statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose I have a table:

```
create table foo (
  col_1     number;
  col_2     number;
);
```

Then I have the following code

```
declare
   col_1    number;
   col_2    number;
begin
   col_1 := 1;
   select col_2 into col_2 from foo where col_1 = col_1;
end;
```

Of course this will not work as expected. How can one make it work without the need to change the variable names?

Comment: I believe you can not; [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS2038) says: "If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence."

Comment: Even if you could circumvent this, it would be considered very bad practice to name your variables the same as column names... you're only going to make maintenance harder on yourself and whoever inherits this code.  Most shops usually decide on a prefix standardization like v_ for variables.

Comment: @KrisJohnston - I know it is bad practice. I have just written some experimental code and did not anticipate using a particular table. I was hoping for a quick fix to make sure it works before having to refactor the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can if you're liberal enough of your definition of *"without the need to change the variable names"*. Reading the fabulous [PL/SQL Name Resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/nameresolution.htm) says:

> If an identifier is declared in a named PL/SQL unit, you can qualify its simple name (the name in its declaration) with the name of the unit (block, subprogram, or package), using this syntax:
>
> `unit_name.simple_identifier_name`

The following example will print `20` as expected:

```
create table foo (a number, b number);

insert into foo values(1, 10);
insert into foo values(2, 20);
insert into foo values(3, 30);

begin
  <<bar>>
  declare
    a number;
    b number;
  begin
    a := 2;
    select b into bar.b from foo where a = bar.a;
    dbms_output.put_line(b);
  end;
end;
/
```

Variable names are not changed. Instead they are hmm ... more qualified :)

Note the following doesn't work:

```
begin
  declare
    a number;
    b number;
  begin
    a := 2;
    select foo.b into b from foo where foo.a = a;
    dbms_output.put_line(b);
  end;
end;
/
```

As the non-qualified `a` in the `select`-statement is interpreted as a column because of the [precedence rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/nameresolution.htm):

> If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dinamic query with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:

```
declare
   col_1    number;
   col_2    number;
begin
   col_1 := 2;
   execute immediate 'select col_2 from foo where col_1 = :a'
   into col_2
   using col_1;   
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and carrying one from @user272735 answer - the following also works

```
create table foo (a number, b number);

insert into foo values(1, 10);
insert into foo values(2, 20);
insert into foo values(3, 30);
/

create procedure bar
as
  a number;
  b number;
begin
  a := 2;
  select b into bar.b from foo where a = bar.a;
  dbms_output.put_line(b);
end;
/
```

Comment: Yes it work, because procedure (as are labelled block (see my example), function and package too) is a named PL/SQL unit.

Comment: I thought I would add it for future reference. Do you know if it works for packages? i.e. the package name instead of the function/procedure name?

Comment: I have never used it myself, but according to documentation this works also with packages.

Comment: @user272735 - Thanks for your help - I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there is one more variation I haven't seen mentioned yet:

```
<<mytest>>
declare
   dummy dual.dummy%type := '?';
begin
   select count(*) into :result from dual d where d.dummy = mytest.dummy;
end;
```

This is the same as user272735's answer but without a layer of wrapping.

(Note not all clients may support this, e.g. PL/SQL Developer 11.1 supports it in Test windows but not in SQL or Command windows.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   declare
       col_1    number;
       col_2    number;
    begin
       col_1 := 1;
       select foo.col_2 into col_2 from foo where foo.col_1 = col_1;

       dbms_output.put_line(col_2);

    end;
/
```

Table name or synonym says that it entity linked to the table. 
Also you can use procedure name, if you do the procedure name.

for example, if proc name is DO, you can do the following:

```
   select foo.col_2 into DO.col_2 from foo where foo.col_1 = DO.col_1;
```