# Select clausule inside pl/sql function return wrong value

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

When I do this:

```
select sum(m.mot)
from rmtq mq
join rmo m on mq.id = m.id
where mq.another = 138;
```

return value = 2, which is correct. But when I put this code inside a function:

```
create or replace function get(another in number) return number
   is ret number := 0;
   begin
      select sum(m.mot)
              into ret
              from rmtq mq
              join rmo m on mq.id = m.id
              where mq.another = another
       return(ret);
    end;
```

and I call:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line(get(138));
```

return value = 39, which is incorrect. What is that 39?

Comment: `another` needs to be qualified with the function name or name the formal parameter differently. Name resolution works from bottom up, it means that your query thinks that `another` is the name of the column in the `rmtq` table, not the name of the formal parameter.

Comment: Try naming the function parameter `another_in` so you know it's the `IN` parameter.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36627313/266304) with a doc link explaining what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments were right to question; lest anyone waste time on this you have to write the names of the parameters correctly, for example:

```
create or replace function get(p_another in number) return number
   is ret number := 0;
   begin
      select sum(m.mot)
              into ret
              from rmtq mq
              join rmo m on mq.id = m.id
              where mq.another = p_another
       return(ret);
    end;
```