# PL/SQL - Can I get warnings when there is ambiguity

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I have the following code:

```
create table test_table (
  col_name   varchar2(20) not null
);
insert into test_table values ('Value 1');
insert into test_table values ('Value 2');
insert into test_table values ('Value 3');
insert into test_table values ('Value 4');
commit;
/
declare
  col_name   varchar2(20) := 'Value 1';
begin
  for c in (select col_name from test_table where test_table.col_name = col_name) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Row ' || c.col_name);
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```

In this code the `where` clause is always true. Obviously this was not the intention. Is it possible to get the compiler to warn me of this?

Comment: Perhaps it was obvious to you that "this was not the intention"; I don't think the compiler was written to judge your intentions. (Besides, the `where` clause is not always true - it will reject NULLs.) The best you can hope for is for something that will ALWAYS raise an alert when you compare a value to itself. The compiler may not do this for you. One way to detect it though, when the compiler sees `col_name = col_name` it rewrites it as `col_name IS NOT NULL`, so if you read the `EXPLAIN PLAN` and know what to look for, you will spot it. I doubt that there is a ready-written warning for it.

Comment: Good point about null. Have modified my code to reflect this

Comment: BTW: Compiler do warning you when there is ambiguity, Like when you join two tables and same field is on both tables. What you have is maybe unnecesary code, but compiler wont check that. For example some use the option `WHERE 1 = 1` because are building a dynamic query with several optional filter so they can just add `AND  option1 = @var` without checking if is the first filter or not

Comment: I adopted a best practice from Thomas Kyte, I always prefix PL/SQL variable with "l_" for local variables, "p_" for parameters, and "g_" for global values. My table column names never start with these strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run your example (in Oracle 11gR2).

**Test table**

```
create table test_table (
  col_name   varchar2(20) not null
);

insert into test_table values ('Value 1');
insert into test_table values ('Value 2');
insert into test_table values ('Value 3');
insert into test_table values ('Value 4');
```

**Turn on all compiler warnings**

```
SQL> alter session set plsql_warnings = 'ENABLE:ALL';
```

**Test procedure**

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file /tmp/afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace procedure test_proc is
  2    col_name   varchar2(20) := 'Value 1';
  3  begin
  4    for c in (select col_name from test_table where test_table.col_name = col_name) loop
  5      dbms_output.put_line('Row ' || c.col_name);
  6    end loop;
  7    commit;
  8* end;
SQL> /

SP2-0804: Procedure created with compilation warnings

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17
SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE TEST_PROC:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/1      PLW-05018: unit TEST_PROC omitted optional AUTHID clause;
         default value DEFINER used

SQL>
```

**Conclusion**

Sorry, but the compiler won't help you :( (We only got non-related warning.)

Obviously you know that PL/SQL name resolution is a well [documented feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36627313/272735) :)

The best you can do in PL/SQL to prevent this and explicitly state your intention is to fully qualify all columns and PL/SQL variables in SQL statements. Enforce the policy in your code reviews.